# Using Django Admin Tables in user views?

Tags: django, django-admin

Is it possibe to use the sortable, searchable tables that admin users get from a non-admin/staff view?

I'd like to be able to make use of it to display data to users without having to install a 3rd party app like django_tables2, dont repeat yourself and all that ...

Comment: wow, that's the mother of all question when starting a django project: will the automatic admin be enough flexible for my project or should I start planning views/urls/templates ? I don't have the answer, but after two years working with Django I decided that if a view or functionality is going to be used by someone else that is not either me or a coworker (with direct communication line) then that view won't be implemented with the django admin interface. This way I can answer the mother of all answers really fast and keep going. Hope it helps you too :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use an external app like [django-filter](https://github.com/alex/django-filter) to cook a searchable model list page outside the admin.